# Error: Column `x` is unknown when apply function

Tags: r, function, error-messaging

I was trying to write a function like below:

```
Q5base_func<- function(x){
  a<-subQ5 %>% group_by(Q1,x) %>% summarise(n = n())
  a <- a[complete.cases(a),] %>% filter(x == 1)
  sum <- sum(a$n)
  a_percent<- a%>%
    mutate(freq= (n/sum)*100)
}
```

I was hoping to get the number of x when x==1 as well as the percentages

Can someone point out where I was wrong? Thank you!

when I apply the function,

```
Q5base_func(subQ5$Q4)
```

error traceback:

```
 Error: Column `x` is unknown 
13.
stop(structure(list(message = "Column `x` is unknown", call = NULL, 
    cppstack = NULL), class = c("Rcpp::exception", "C++Error", 
"error", "condition"))) 
12.
grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) 
11.
grouped_df(groups$data, groups$group_names, .drop) 
10.
group_by.data.frame(., Q1, x) 
9.
group_by(., Q1, x) 
8.
function_list[[i]](value) 
7.
freduce(value, `_function_list`) 
6.
`_fseq`(`_lhs`) 
5.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
4.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
3.
withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)) 
2.
subQ5 %>% group_by(Q1, x) %>% summarise(n = n()) 
1.
Q5base_func(subQ5$Q11)
```

sample dataset is something like this:

```
Q1  Qx
1   1
2   0
2   1
3   0
3   1
3   1
```

Comment: Are you calling the function correctly? ex `Q5base_func(1)`,  Without seeing a sample of your data, I believe you what to `filter(Q==x)` and not group by, but this is just a guess without additional clarification of your question.

Comment: Thank you! I have update the sample dataset. Could you give some suggestions based on that? If it's not sufficient, I will add more.@Dave2e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplished is possible as a one liner.

```
subQ5 <- structure(list(Q1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                    Qx = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

library(dplyr)

Q5base_func <- function(df, x) {
   df %>% filter(complete.cases(.))  %>% 
   group_by(Q1) %>% 
 #  mutate(sumx=sum(Qx==x), percent=sum(Qx==x)/n())     #add columns and keeps all of the data
    summarise(sumx=sum(Qx==x), percent=sum(Qx==x)/n())  #summarize the results
}

x<-1
answer <-Q5base_func(subQ5, x)
answer
```

Comment: This worked well! I really appreciate your suggestion. The thing is I have more than ten same lines to run. So I want to make it a function.

Comment: Yes it is potentially easy to enclose this in a function, but what changes just the x value or the dataframe(assuming dataframe structure stays the same) or both?

Comment: `a<-subQ5 %>% group_by(Q1,x) %>% summarise(n = n())` is going to add a new line which is n counts, and this `a_percent<- a%>% mutate(freq= (n/sum)*100)` line is going to add another column "percent". So I think it's the data frame change

Comment: Thank you so much! I also used dplyr. Your code helped me to simplify mine.